# Making traffic simulation GUI from turn based to simultaneous

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm working on a traffic simulation project and I've come pretty far with the road network (it's static), how it looks in GUI and vehicle steering.

Biggest thing I'm missing is any kind of realistic interaction between vehicles. Since my execution at the moment is turn based for example junction behaviour of the vehicles is super clunky. There can be 4 vehicles going straight from a junction and if there's even a one square space between any 2 of them the turning vehicle will squeeze in to that square.

I was given this as a source material: http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/ which talks about velocity vectors and all that stuff. But from what I understand stuff like velocity and acceleration are not really possible to implement on my turn based system since vehicles move square by square.

How would i need to approach getting rid of this square/turn based system into a live action one? Or is there some way to make this turn based system more realistic since getting rid of this would probably mean me making almost everything from scratch again. Here is a pic of my GUI, I've removed the square edges to make it look more realistic but essentially every vehicle moves 1 square per turn. [traffic sim GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GhoM.png)

This is a simple move function for my current turn/square based system:

```
def move(self, direction):

    target = self.get_location().get_neighbor(direction)
    current_square = self.get_location_square()
    target_square = self.get_world().get_square(target)
    self.spin(direction)
    if target_square.is_empty():
        current_square.remove_vehicle()
        self.location = target
        target_square.set_vehicle(self)
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

So from the base material exists:

Simple Vehicle Model:

```
    mass          scalar

    position      vector

    velocity      vector

    max_force     scalar

    max_speed     scalar

    orientation   N basis vectors
```

But how does this relate to my square based grid? Can a vehicle be simultaneously half in 2 squares?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems that your approach won't work due to its concept: the issue is not about occupying more than one square, but that you're only allowing one vehicle per square, which would create some issues for the velocity and acceleration.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I was thinking of maybe making a single square smaller and making the default speed be more than 1 square when slowing would be possible.  Even if I make it ok for 2 vehicles to occupy one square how would it show in GUI if a vehicle is between 2 squares?